# Add new object to fullcalendar from Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I am trying to add new events from an ajax to fullcalendar events
Here is what I've tried

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'ajax link',
headers: {
    dateType: "json",
    "Authorization":"something"
},
dataType: "json",
success: function (res){
  var wow = res;
}
})
```

```
var EventsField = {
  id: 1,
  events: [
    {
      id: '1',
      start: curYear+'-'+curMonth+'-08T08:30:00',
      end: curYear+'-'+curMonth+'-08T13:00:00',
      title: 'Some Title',
      backgroundColor: '#bff2f2',
      borderColor: '#00cccc',
      description: 'Some text'
    },
  ]
};
```

So, from ajax I get variables like the ones present in the events object, and I want to get those from ajax and put them into the events objects.

Thanks!

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed this one helped me